# Filter on a string containing an apostrophe (') in Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

I want to know how can I Filter on a string containing an apostrophe/single quote ( ' ) in Jaspersoft Studio using the domain ( Condition Editor) ?

Condition editor:

[image]

The error:

[image]

Comment: http://zupimages.net/up/17/18/fhmf.png   http://zupimages.net/up/17/18/sqx4.png

Comment: screenshot

http://zupimages.net/up/17/18/fhmf.png

http://zupimages.net/up/17/18/sqx4.png

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/EsKVQ

Comment: Did you try to escape quote like this: `I don&apos;t`?

Comment: Yes I tried to escape with  &apos;  and other things like  '' ;  \\  ; \'   without success

Comment: I found the solution,
You have to put in Filter Expression this  EQUALS($F{Field},"Your ' String")

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,
You have to put in Filter Expression this  EQUALS($F{Field},"Your'String")